# Algorithm for Broken Priority Queue

Tags: algorithm, insert, priority-queue, little-o

IF a priority queue has two operations: `insert` and `broken_min`.
Where `broken_min` returns either the first or second minimum item.

These cannot both be implemented in o(logn) time.
I think this is because insert uses broken_min and would then have to do more checks to see if it has the maximum or not.

Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: A priority queue implemented as a min-heap can find the min in constant time. I'm not sure I understand what the issue is?

Comment: The only two operators it has is insert and broken_min.
This means that insert will have a larger then o(logn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe you're correct.

A priority-queue is typically implemented as a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29):

> A heap is a specialized [binary-]tree-based data structure ... the keys of parent nodes are less than or equal to those of the children and the lowest key is in the root node (min heap).

`broken_min` can be implemented in O(1) since one of the children will be the second largest element, so we can just check both.

But `insert` will take Ω(log n), which isn't o(log n) (but would indeed be O(log n)).

I doubt you'll find a priority-queue implementation that could satisfy the given running times, but saying it's *impossible* would be irresponsible.

**Note:** I assume you meant little-o (a strict upper bound, as opposed to big-O, which is a greater-or-equal upper bound) given the tag, although big-O is used most of them time, and little-o is almost never used (as far as I've seen).